# Error while concatenating lists in python

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment for one of my classes at school where I need to concatenate two lists together.  I am using the code:

```
flowers = ["rose", "bougainvillea", "yukka", "marigold", "daylily", "lily of the valley"]

thorny = flowers[0:3]
poisonous = flowers[-1]
dangerous = flowers[0:3] + flowers[-1]
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
dangerous = list(set(flowers[0:3] + flowers[-1]))   
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I was wondering why this doesn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: `dangerous = flowers[0:3] + flowers[-1:]`

Answer (score 7):

`flowers[0:3]` returns a list while `flowers[-1]` returns a string, so you are adding a string to a list. You can use `flowers[-1:]` to return a list instead.